# One form, 7 radio button groups, once answer per group, answers can't be the same in each group

Tags: html, dreamweaver, radio-group

first time posting.

Not new to programming but very new to HTML and web coding. Using adobe dreamweaver. (any and all software, tools, sites, material suggestions appreciated)

objective: I need to make 13 groups of radio buttons with 13 selections in each group (1-13) on a form. There can only be one answer per group and the answer in each group can not be picked in a second group. Its something along the lines of, here are 13 events, put them in order, 1 you liked the most 13 you liked the least.

Ive done some online research and came across a post on here that had more than one group of radio buttons but only one selection for each group. I need each group to have a selection thats not the same as the other groups selections so group 1 and 4 can't both have the same selection of 10.

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

I have thought about having each group have its own page and submit button. The submit button would send the selection and move to the next event.

The way I'm currently trying is to have them all on one page.

Of course the easiest way would be best but not afraid of a challenge. Am I in over my head?

Comment: I recommend Sublime text 3. Its highly customizable and it has great work flow enhancing tools :)

Sublime Text 3: http://www.sublimetext.com/3
Plugins: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-text-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, normally I would not have helped with this question since I believe that you should first try something out, and then present the issue you are experiencing (Not just ask for code). However this puzzle intrigued me so I came up with the below solution. (For this demo i used 3 groups of 3, but with this code you can use any number of groups and any number of inputs per group

First the HTML: I grouped the inputs together and gave each type of input their own id. For each group I want tied together (in this example the first and last group) I gave the inputs a the same classes (All the first options in a group have the same class, all the 2nd, etc.

```
<div class="group">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="option1" id="test1">
  <label for="test1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="option2" id="test2">
  <label for="test2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" class="option3" id="test3">
  <label for="test3">Option 3</label>
</div> <!-- /group -->
<div class="group">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" class="option1" id="test4">
  <label for="test4">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" class="option2" id="test5">
  <label for="test5">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" class="option3" id="test6">
  <label for="test6">Option 3</label>
</div> <!-- /group -->
<div class="group">
  <input type="radio" name="group3" class="option1" id="test7">
  <label for="test7">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group3" class="option2" id="test8">
  <label for="test8">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group3" class="option3" id="test9">
  <label for="test9">Option 3</label>
</div> <!-- /group -->
```

Next, the Javascript (you can look at the inline comments in the fiddle for further breakdown): When a radio button is clicked, I make all the inputs with the same class disabled. I then loop through the siblings to see which ones I can re-enable. (Inputs that are checked in another group will be set to / remain disabled)

```
function radioButtonClicked() {
  var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + theClass).not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).siblings('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
      var otherClasses = $(this).attr('class');
      $('.' + otherClasses).each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          return false;
        } else {
          $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
  });
}
$('.group input[type="radio"]').on('change', radioButtonClicked);
```

With this method, users will only be able to click on a radio button that has not been previously selected. If an answer is changed, the other options will become available again IF there are no other similar inputs selected. Here is the fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/owkcq1vs/45/

Comment: Thank you very much. I am extremely glad you decided to respond. Unfortunately it seems my knowledge of web is way less than i had previously thought. I can see how it works to an extent and i see it working in the fiddle. Moving that into my own project to try and understand it further makes me realize how little i knew about the subject as a whole before hand. I will have to look at an online course or two to try to grasp a better understanding of how it all works and where to put what. Thank you once again, if anything, helping me go in the right direction.